# Bootstrap 3 with Skrollr site getting cut off on ios?

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, safari, responsive-design, skrollr

I've been creating a portfolio website for a friend. In an attempt to make the site responsive and artsy, I chose to pull in twitter bootstrap and skrollr. I noticed that in safari in iOS that the site seems to be cut off at a certain point. Has anyone else ran into this issue before? I have provided a link below in case anyone notices anything obvious.

http://jennaparysek.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people (including myself) are having troubles when using skrollr on mobile devices. In order to use both "fixed" and "relative/absolute" position at the same time, you have to put all the divs that are not fixed inside a div called `#skrollr-body`

However, the real problem is that your skrollr is being confused when getting the height of your
skrollr-body. you can try to put `forceHeight: false` inside your `skrollr.init()`

if that doesn't work, it might because skrollr doesn't know where is the end of `#skrollr-body`, so just put an empty div after your `#skrollr-body` and give it a keyframe. It should works just fine now :)